# Fedora behaves sluggish after the upgrade 24 → 25

Tags: fedora, performance

I have upgraded my Fedora installation from 24 to 25. Since then, things that were done instantly before *sometimes* take half a second now. Examples are:

- Switching the workspace in Awesome WM
- Typing something into the terminal (Konsole, fish shell)
- Pasting with the mousewheel (e.g. into Freemind, a Java Mindmap software)
- Starting a new terminal window
- Performing an action in Firefox

I do not quote know where this is coming from. Since it impacts a lot of programs from various toolkits (Qt, GTK, Java), I am not really sure what is going on. This regression is not catastrophic but rather annoying.

My display manager is LightDM, I use Awesome WM and a bunch of KDE programs. `htop` does not show anything out of the ordinary. The idle load (Konsole, Firefox, Spotify) is now at around 5%, I remember it to be lower and usually going down to 1%.

How could I diagnose this regressions? Any log that might help?

Comment: Did you move from X11 server to Wayland?

Comment: @meuh I don't think so with Awesome WM.

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl -f` and note any errors particularly when it becomes sluggish. Also, maybe run `iotop`?

Comment: I ran journalctl, albeit as a user. There were no interesting messages.